# Splunk Connect for Kube - how to get logs for my script

Tags: azure-aks, splunk

I have containerized my script that logs to standard output with docker , pushed the image to Azure Container Registry and deployed to AKS. I need to see my logs in Splunk, therefore I used an HEC with the following library: https://github.com/splunk/splunk-connect-for-kubernetes/blob/develop/helm-chart/splunk-connect-for-kubernetes/values.yaml.

I put in the values.yaml, in the section logs, the information regarding my hello world script. Unfortunately I am not able to see the logs of my hello world application in SPlunk. Any hint?

Here is an extract of values.yaml

```
 helloworld5:
      from:
        pod: helloworld5-5dc446c649-9bfzm 
        container: helloworld5
```